# CSS: Best way to format layout

Tags: html, css, formatting

I would like to know what the best way is to format the following layout:
(with eveything aligned and spaced neatly):

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class"wrapper">
  <img alt="Image 1" src="images/image1.png" />
  <div class="description">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following but the vertical-align property does not seem to be working as I cannot align the top of the h1 with the top of the image:

```
img, div.description {
    float: left;
}

div.description { margin-left: 10px; vertical-align: top; }

h1 { background: blue;  }
p { background: red; }
```

What if instead of how the right hand side part is displayed below,
we wanted the right hand side to also be vertically centered instead
of being top aligned?

Here is the JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/johngoche99/ZPKZj/1/

OK, to keep the text from dropping down below when the browser is resized it is necessary to specify the width of the wrapper element to something like 700px. Then it works.

Thanks.

Comment: try to learn css, post your problems not your tasks

Comment: You can't use `vertical-align` unless an element has `display:table-cell;` on it **and** `display:table;` on its parent. You have some research and experimentation to do, this question borders on closeable IMO.

Comment: @DominicB-c Correction: vertical-align only works on table-cell or *inline* elements.  The difference being that when used on table-cell elements, it dictates how its children are vertically aligned.  On inline elements, it dictates how they are vertically aligned relative to the surrounding inline elements.

Comment: I stand corrected, last time I had a look it said only table-cell, thanks. I've only recently started looking at the original docs, used to look for blogs because it looked too confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in css you need to do this

```
img{
    float: left;
    height: 300px
}

div{
    float: left;
}

h1{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #584480;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

p{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E24480;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

nothing more ...

Hope this will help you ...

Comment: Thanks, you've done a nice job of setting the square colored backgrounds and have them properly aligned. However the clear: both; par seems like it's not needed.

Comment: thats right, there is no need to "clear:both", but I forgot to clear it , thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with simple CSS.

```
img, div{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPKZj/2/

IRL, do NOT use this CSS.  It is far too generic to be useful in any production environment.  You might give your elements IDs or classes to allow the rules to be much more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPKZj/9/)

You want to use css here. You will add an ID to the first div like `<div id="wrapper">` this is your main div. Then in the second div you add `<div id="headings">` for the headings. then in your css add the beneath code. (note: this isn't the best css code ever. but it works :))

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img alt="Image 1" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/005/cache/green-iguana_563_600x450.jpg" />
  <div id="headings">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper img{
    float: left;\
    margin-right: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

#headings{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

h1{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your CSS did not work for me. How do I position the top of the H1 with the top of the img?

Comment: Thanks. Seems like more of a hack though. Will break if I change font attributes on the h1 heading.

Comment: Yes, it's more of an hack. You can instead use the h1 code mutja provided.

Comment: Yes, although that code does relect what I drew above, I really meant the top of the h1 header to be at the top. Also the question of how to have both boxes centered in the middle is still unanswered. I could add a top-border but would like to do it in a way that I won't have to update this piece of information if the image height changes.

Comment: You want all the content in the center? that's easy :) will edit my answer.

Comment: I made the #wrapper div 960px wide and centered it using margin: 0 auto; this way if you zoom out the content is within the center.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you markup need a little change to be more, khm right;
HTML:

```
    <div id="all">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <img class="side_image" alt="Image 1" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/005/cache/green-iguana_563_600x450.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Paragraph 1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar { float: left; }
#sidebar { margin-right: 40px; }
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

link to look how it will be:
http://jsfiddle.net/56Z7C/1/

Comment: OK, so adding the extra div to nest the image in did the job for you. Thanks, but could you explain some of the theory of why this is necessary? Also, this does not answer the second question of how to vertically align the text on the right instead of top align it (in part II of the question). Thanks.

Comment: 1st part of you comment:
It's not so necessary in your case for now- but it'll be more flexible, if you'll wrap this img into div, for example:
Now everything ok, but in future you'll need to do little change- you'll want to text appears only on right side on the image- don't matter how many characters you'll type there.
Look here - http://jsfiddle.net/56Z7C/2/ thats what happens in your markup (and my markup too), **BUT** it takes only write a little jquery script for my markup to make text appears only in right side and not go under image.
please look here: http://jsfiddle.net/56Z7C/3/

Comment: 2nd part: There is default top margin of h1 element, I just rewrite it with margin-top: 0 in code; You dont need to worry about vertical alignment in blocks (only in tables).

Comment: 3nd part :)   :
if you resize it too smal- that word **Header** can't здфсув there- than it's right that block jumps down;

Answer (score 1):

Vertical-align only works on tables. If you want to do that with `div`s, you could try using [`display: table`](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#table):

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <img alt="Image 1" width="100" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/005/cache/green-iguana_563_600x450.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell" id="stuff">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }
#stuff { vertical-align: middle; }
```

This has the advantage of not being dependent on sizes/margins of elements, but is unsupported in IE7 and below. As all things in life, `display: table` is a tradeoff.